# Robust covariance and OGK outlier detection

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, outliers, covariance-matrix, robust

I'm calculating the robust covariance of a data set in order to use mahalanobis distance for outlier detection. There are few methods to calculate the covariance in the equation. Using the Fast-MCD method I got non-deterministic results, which led me to use the OGK method (Orthogonalized Gnanadesikan Kettenring) that produced deterministic results. 
I'm trying to understand the difference between Fast-MCD and OGK, and specifically how the OGK method works?

Comment: The working of the OGK method is well explained in many places. It's quiet simple. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrcov/vignettes/rrcov.pdf) for example (page 14 and 15 of 'An Object Oriented Framework for Robust Multivariate Analysis' by Todorov and Filzmosez). What is not so often explained is the cost associated with determinism in the context of robust multivariate statistics. I gave this a stab [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243336/603).

Comment: Maybe, if after reading the one page explanation of the ogk method you still have question, I suggest you edit your question to focus on those.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I read the the pages and I don't understand the algorithm and the intuition of this method. Can you please help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To justify the OGK, you need to see the following chain:

- Outlier detection and robust estimation are essentially equivalent problems,
- At its core, outlier detection is related to the problem of (center-outward) ranking of the data,
- Ranking is much more complicated when you have several variables than if you only have one.

For these reasons, uni-variate robust estimators are much simpler than multivariate ones (including computationally).

The idea of the OGK is to construct [a multivariate estimator of scatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) (like the classical covariance matrix but [robust to outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics)) by combining $O(p^2)$ univariate outlier-robust estimates of scale (where $p$ is the number of variables in your data).

---

Intermezzo:

For the [classical covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $\pmb V(\pmb X)$ of a data matrix $\bf X$ (with colunms $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^p$), it holds that:

$$\pmb V_{ii}(\pmb X) = s^2(X_i)$$

--where $s^2(X_i)$ is the classical univariate estimator of variance applied to the vector $X_i$-- and

$$\pmb V_{ij}(\pmb X) = \frac{1}{4}\left(s^2\left(X_i+X_j\right)-s^2\left(X_i-X_j\right)\right)$$

---

The OGK is based on two ideas.

Use the equations above to construct $\pmb C$ (a robust scatter matrix) by substituting $s^2()$  in the equations above by $m^2()$, a robust estimator of scale (for example the square of the [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)). This is the first idea.

The resulting matrix is only guaranteed positive semi-definite when $m()=s()$. 
So, in general, $\pmb C$  is not positive semi definite. This is an annoying flaw for an estimator of scatter. Therefore we need to apply some additional step, in the case of the OGK called orthogonalization step, to $\pmb C$ to find a positive semi-definite matrix that is, in some sense, 'close to $\pmb C$' --this is the second idea--:

- Rescale your data, columnswise: $\pmb Y = \pmb D^{-1}\pmb X$ (where $\pmb D = \text{diag}(m^2(X_1),\ldots,m^2(X_p)$)
- project the rescaled data  on $\pmb E$, the eigenvector of $\pmb C(\pmb Y)$  (the robust scatter matrix computed using the formula above applied to the on rescaled data $Y$), i.e. $\pmb T=\pmb E^{\top}\pmb Y$;
- compute a diagonal matrix of 'robust variances'
  $\pmb\Lambda=\text{diag}(m^2(T_1),\ldots,m^2(T_p))$;
- set $\pmb\mu(\pmb X)=\pmb A\pmb m$ where $\pmb m=(m(T_1),\ldots,m(T_p))$ 
  and compute the positive definite matrix $\pmb\varSigma(\pmb X)=\pmb A \pmb\Lambda \pmb A^T$, where $\pmb A= \pmb D\pmb E$.

Then, $\pmb\mu(\pmb X)$ and $\pmb\varSigma(\pmb X)$ are called respectively the raw OGK estimates of location and scatter. $\pmb\varSigma(\pmb X)$ is now guaranteed to be positive semi-definite. Moreover, it is in some sense close to $\pmb C(\pmb X)=\pmb D\pmb C(\pmb Y)\pmb D$.

The raw OGK estimates of location and scatter trivially inherit the breakdown point (a measure of robustness of an estimator to the presence of outliers in the data) of the measure of scale used in the computation of $\pmb C$ (for example the breakdown point is about 50%, which is best, when $m()$ is the MAD).

You asked for a comparison with another 50% breakdown point algorithm to estimate the scatter matrix robustly, FastMCD. Contrary to FastMCD, OGK is a deterministic algorithm. Also contrary to FastMCD, OGK is [not affine equivariant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243336/603).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How did you get to the equation of V(i,j) of the classical covariance?

Comment: @Lisa: you can derive it from $\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ and $\text{Var}(X-Y) = \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ by re-ordering the terms.